# how to stop form submit/postback with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, forms

I have a button to submit my form with a postback, i would like to run some valuation and if all is not well show error messages and stop the postback. I have managed to get my code to enter my onsubmit function but am unable to stop the postback.

Form:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" style="width:100%; height:400px; margin:0px; padding:2px;" class="BackColor5" enableviewstate="true" onsubmit="validateForms()">
```

Function:

```
function validateForms() {
   if ($('#ddAssets').text() == "") {
      $('#ddAssets').css({border: "1px solid red"});
      return false;
   }
}
```

Button:

```
<ICCM:ICCMImageButton ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" onclick="btnSubmit_Click" TabIndex="6" meta:resourcekey="btnResSubmit" PostBack="true"  style="display:inline-table;" AccessKey="S"/>
```

btnSubmit_Click is a function in the code behind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Return the result of `validateForms()` in `onsubmit`

```
onsubmit="return validateForms()"
```

Return `true` when validation succeed and `false` otherwise.

```
function validateForms() {
   if ($('#ddAssets').text() == "") {
      $('#ddAssets').css({border: "1px solid red"});
      return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

Comment: It has stopped the submit, but now it wont submit at all, even if i return true

Comment: Do you have asp:button on which you want to submit you better call this validation function on that

Comment: Sorry jquery.text() always returned "" as its a drop down. Every thing works fine now, thanks for the help.